# banner fix the width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with a banner. I deleted all the rest of the code.

I create it as a imagebutton.

The layout has a image as layout, for example in the hdpi, the size is: 720x1200 px, and the imagebutton is 720x200

this is the imageButton:

[image]

but the imagebutton doesn't fix the width, but I dont find the mistake!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sabadell_but"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_sabadell" />  

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I get the imagebutton fixed the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sabadell_but"
        android:background="@drawable/banner_sabadell"
        android:contentDescription="@string/infoDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        />  

</LinearLayout>
```

As you have used `wrap_content` for the imagebutton, it is forcing your button to match the imageButton width. And as you have set image as src, it is not scaling the image, For this purpose, you can set image as `android:background` rather giving it as `android:src`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` for your `ImageButton`.